# Run Batch File Before Windows 7 User Login to Start VLC Web Interface

Tags: service, batch-file, startup, vlc, windows-7-x64

I would like to run a batch file I have that executes the following before a user logs on:

```
start "VLC web Interface" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I http
```

Currently I have this in my Startup folder but I would like this batch file to be executed before a user is logged in on Windows 7.  The goal is to start VideoLAN's Web Interface as a service without requiring a user to login.  This way the computer can be turned on, and media can be streamed to my devices without choosing a user profile on the login screen.

To be clear, I would like this batch file to run **BEFORE a user logs in**, not after.

Any ideas?

Comment: I still have no answer for how to accomplish this BEFORE a user logs in.  Any ideas?

Comment: you should run it as service. Example from here works fine for me http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Windows/How_to_Create_a_Windows_Service

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer above would work. However, my preference of how to do it would be a little different. The effect is more or less the same, but I find it a little easier to use the Task Scheduler.

1. Open the Windows Task Scheduler.
2. Create a basic task.
3. Name it whatever you want, such as VLC Web Interface.
4. Click Next, and choose When the computer starts.
5. Click Next, and choose Start a program.
6. Click Next, and click Browse, then select your batch script.
7. Click Next, and click Finish.

It will now be in your Task Scheduler list of scheduled tasks. From there, you can right click on it and run it now, or end it, or whatever, and it will run every time the computer starts. Any user should be able to do this, whether on a domain or not, and even if you are using Windows Home (in which case you can't use gpedit.msc anyway).

Answer (score 6):

Create a local group policy object for a startup script.

Start up scripts run pre login.

To create what you are after:

- Open a run box
- type in "gpedit.msc" (without the quotes)
- Expand Computer Configuration
- Expand Windows Settings
- Select Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)
- Double click Startup
- Click Show Files and copy/paste your batch file in to this folder
- Click the Add button on the startup properties
- Click Browse and double click on your script to choose it.
- "OK" out of all windows to apply the new settings.

The selected script will now run every time the PC starts. 
If the PC is part of a Windows Active Directory domain these settings will be overridden with AD Group Policy, in which case the admin of the network should be doing this for you.

**Edit:**
It's been a few years since I wrote this, while this would work, it's probably simpler to go with Automate Everything's answer and use Task Scheduler to perform an "At Startup" action.

Comment: How do we restart/update/close that task.. It's not showing in the CMD