# Runing python-script after winlogon.exe

Tags: python, windows, winlogon

I'm trying to run the python script right after the user is logged in. I tried the batch file that runs the script to add to the task scheduler with the trigger "at login", but the script also runs after the windows is fully loaded, the desktop appears and after a while. Is it possible to somehow increase the priority of executing a script (or exe-shnik) or just to run it immediately after the user login appeared in the system (for example, after running winlogon.exe)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Batch File Before Windows 7 User Login to Start VLC Web Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829337/run-batch-file-before-windows-7-user-login-to-start-vlc-web-interface)

Comment: winlogon.exe executes the configured user initialization application. The default app is userinit.exe, which executes the user's logon script (if found relative to the system's "netlogon" share) and the user's desktop shell, which defaults to explorer.exe. It doesn't wait for the logon script to return before executing the shell.

Comment: winlogon.exe also signals services with a session-change message. This is how the Task Scheduler and Group Policy Client get notified to run logon tasks/scripts. For both of the latter you can directly run `"path\to\python.exe" "path\to\script.py"`. Note that group-policy logon "scripts" (any executable, really) are executed by the Group Policy Client service and are not the same as the account's legacy logon batch script that userinit.exe runs.

Answer (score 0):

Paste here : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

else try to [load Desktop before logging in](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/111046-having-desktop-ready-before-login-screen.html) + StartUp

else make your own credential Provider and launch your script before calling to LogonUserEx *(a little overkill ?)*